# Texturing a less than perfect object in photoshop/Affinty Photo

Tags: adobe-photoshop, texture, mockup

I am not a photoshopper, but I have been given a task to make a mockup for a customer. Basically, I have to take the texture from one bag, and apply it to another, without it looking awful. Bellow is the base bag.

[image: Base Bag image]

As you can see, it's got a texture and from what I have seen on various tutorials, this will make things like displacement maps a bit of a hassle.

The texture I have been asked to use is bellow
[image: bag texture]

Things tried

- So far I have tried playing with a displacement map
- Creating a texture brush and painting in the sections.
- I have also tried to scrub the texture off, and have it as a sort of negative, to then apply the texture in.

I will admit up front, I don't fully understand the process of things like photoshop, so there could be a really simple way for me to do this, and I am simply missing it. I am more comfortable around vectors.

I ask for help, as I am likely to be given similar jobs like this in the future, and want to learn and understand the technique associated with something like this

Regards

Dev

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZW3eh.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using just a small part of the new texture:

[image]

- **Menu Edit** > **Define Pattern**

[image: pattern]

- At the *New Bag* file, duplicate the *Bag Layer*
- Make a selection of the *New Bag* fabric
- **Menu Image** > **Adjustments** > **Desaturate**

[image: Desaturate]

- Using this selection > Make a **Mask**

[image: Mask]

- Click twice the layer to apply a **Layer Effect** > Choose **Pattern Overlay** > Use the *New Pattern*, mode= Darker Color

[image: Pattern Overlay]

**Result**

[image: Bag]

With 75% Pattern Overlay opacity

[image: 75% Pattern Overlay]

Comment: Thank you for your time and efforts in answering my question :) This perfect and easily understandable.

Answer (score 0):

One quick, minor but important addition: if you are using the excellent technique that @Danielillo has shown you above (using **Layer Effects Pattern Overlay**) and you then find that you also need to ***recolour*** your chosen new pattern, you can *easily* apply a **Layer Effect Gradient Overlay**, set to **Colour** or **Hue** depending upon the final effect you need.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Affinity the available tool set is smaller than in Photoshop, but the job is still possible.

At first we must make a careful selection to separate the fabric parts of the red bag from the rest. With that selection we make two layers. One which contains only the fabric parts and another, where the fabric parts are hidden with a layer mask.

Deletion isn't recommended because a selection and its inverse easily creates a no-man's land which is one pixel wide transparent zone. It happened here, too, but after noticing it I could expand the selection one pixel and made a new mask.

[image]

The selection was drawn with the pen. Actually your white background was removed at first. No color or contrast based methods are accurate enough if the photo wasn't taken specifically targeting to easy background removal.

The original fabric fine texture isn't very harmful in this case. Affinity Photo has a handy frequency separation filtering which can be used, if it was, but it's not needed now. In Photoshop one would use Smart Blur to remove fabric fine structure. We'll fix it at the end, if needed.

NOTE: The original fabric has brightness variance, which will be useful.

The red color of the fabric isn't wanted. A BW adjustment layer removes it. Also one needs good contrast. Another adjustment layer is added for it. NOTE: We want to kill the red color from all parts => The BW adjustment layer is above both.

[image]

Your new texture is difficult to use (except as very dark). It's unsharp, non-uniformly lighted and harmfully curved. I believe the next pattern is plausible enough. It will finally get a slight blur because it's not pixel perfect.

[image]

This is a cheat. It's in Affinity Designer because vector shapes are a little easier there. It's exported as PNG and brought back as wrapped bitmap pattern fill.

The fill pattern was copied and pasted to Affinity Photo and rasterized to normal pixel layer,it got a layer mask with the fabric parts layer (=select he emptiness, invert the selection, goto texture layer and create a layer mask)

The texture layer got blending mode hard light and the curves layer was adjusted for good bag feature visibility:

[image]

Actually the new texture is dark red. Having original colors in the non-fabric parts can be a good thing:

[image]

The BW layer was moved to lower.

This is not at all plausible, because the texture is too straight. Fortunately Affinity Photo has extremely usable mesh warping tool to add some curvature to the pattern:

[image]

Believe: There's no need to be exact.

After some warp tweaks, adding a slight sub-pixel (radius=0.2px) gaussian blur to the original red fabric fine texture and inserting a white background we have:

[image]